# Clarity on my Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list. I have a problem with this piece of code. Say, I want to create a list which should have 3 items and the items are 45, 56, 67. The output that i am getting is 0, 45, 56. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int b);
void display();

struct node

{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*head, *ptr;

int main()
{
int a,b;
int i = 0;
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

printf("enter the number of entries:\n");
scanf("%d",&a);

while(i<a)
{
printf("enter the value:\n");
scanf("%d", &b);
add(b);
display();
i++;
}

return 0;

}

void display()
{
struct node *list = head;

while(list->next != 0)
{
printf("%d -> ",list->data);
list = list->next;
}

}

void add(int b)
{
struct node *p = head;
struct node *ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptr->data = b;
ptr->next = 0;

while(p->next!=0)
{
p = p->next;
}

p->next = ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at main

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->next = NULL;//necessary to set to NULL
```

at display

```
printf("%d -> ", list->next->data);//The top node is not used
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `display()` in a separate loop after you are done with the adding...